# Inserting Data in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL  query to insert data into my table but for some reason, It's not inserting the data into the table

When I var_dump the execute statement if returning false.

```
foreach($information as $data){
     $name = $data['name'];
     $id = $data['id'];
    $time = $data['time'];

    $query =  "INSERT INTO students(name,id,time)"
               ."VALUES('$name','$id','time')";
                  //prepare and execute
               $stmt = $psql->prepare($query);
               $result = $stmt->execute();

               var_dump($result);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably `'$name'` is not being understood in the query. Also, you should check for the existence of those variables

Try doing something like this

```
   if (isset($name, $id, $time)) {
    $query = 
    'DO$$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from students where name = \'$name\')
            THEN
            INSERT INTO student("name", "id", "time")
            VALUES (\'$name\', \'$id\', \'$time\')
        END IF;
    END;
    $$;'
}
```

Comment: After writing you above mention code how would I execute it?

Comment: Just put it inside a variable `$query` see my updated answer